# Remote queries to Cassandra from Android

Tags: android, rest, cassandra, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm developing for the first time an app that needs to do queries to a remote Cassandra DB.
I have found on web the Datastax Java Cassandra [driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) and Java Spark-Cassandra [connectors](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and now I'm trying to do calls with them.

Can anyone tell me if exist a way to do calls via Retrofit? 
Is there any converter or adapter?

Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know Retrofit is a HTTP client, but Cassandra doesn't provide an HTTP API, so you need to implement your own web service, which will provide HTTP access to Cassandra from your Android app.